# Trying to iterate through numbers in a table rather than displayng all the values for each number in each cell

Tags: python, django, database

I am currently attempting to make a table which takes the lab number for a sample and returns the 'Value 2' of that number(I know it's a bad name but it's what I'm being made to work with) so far I can retrieve the data when a specific lab number is searched for, however if I just have a list of lab numbers in the table, it either displays as 'None' or it starts listing every lab number in order in each cell, as a dictionary.

The code that isn't displaying the data properly:

```
def GetValue2(self, _pageOfWorkflowCases):
    _resultsDict = {}
    for row in _pageOfWorkflowCases:
        LabNumber = row['LABNO']
        with connection.cursor() as _cursor:
            _cursor.execute("{CALL dbo.uspShireXGetValue2(%s)}", [LabNumber])
            _results = self.utilities.ConvertCursorListToDict(_cursor)

            if _results:
                _resultsDict[LabNumber] = _results.get['VALUE2']
    return _resultsDict
```

The code that displays a lab number when it's searched for:

```
def GetValue2(self, _LabNumber):
        with connection.cursor() as _cursor:
            _cursor.execute("{CALL dbo.uspShireXGetValue2(%s)}", [_LabNumber])
            _results = self.utilities.ConvertCursorListToDict(_cursor)

            if _results:
                _results = self.utilities.ConvertCursorListToDict(_cursor)
    return _results
```

Comment: How do I return a single result that corresponds to the lab number in the table, rather than returning every value 2 in every cell?